# Redirect all requests on subfolder to subfolder/index.html with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, laravel, laravel-4

At the moment I'm using this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^((?!app/).*)$ /app/$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm trying to get it so that anything starting with `/app` goes to the app folder, but when I hit `/app/debates` it gets handled by the `index.php` file. If I hit `/app` then it does get routed correctly.

How can I modify this to handle all sub-URLs too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this rule **just below** `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteRule ^app/ - [L,NC]
```